# Can't view order in magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I've been setting up a fresh magento 1.4.0.1 install, working great so far. I did some test orders just to see. Everything works fine, but when I click on "view order" under "my orders", I get a bunch of error messages:

> There has been an error processing
> your request
>
> Notice: iconv_substr()
> [function.iconv-substr]: Unknown error
> (0)  in
> /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php
> on line 98
>
> Trace:
> #0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(8,
> 'iconv_substr() ...',
> '/data/web/A1423...', 98, Array)
> #1 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php(98):
> iconv_substr('1', 0, 50, 'UTF-8')
>
> #2 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php(173):
> Mage_Core_Helper_String->substr('1',
> 0, 50)
>
> #3 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php(112):
> Mage_Core_Helper_String->str_split('1',
> 50)
>
> #4 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml(58):
> Mage_Core_Helper_String->splitInjection('1')
>
> #5 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189):
> include('/data/web/A1423...')
>
> #6 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
>
> #7 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>
> #8 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>
> #9 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Items/Abstract.php(137):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>
> #10 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/items.phtml(52):
> Mage_Sales_Block_Items_Abstract->getItemHtml(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item))
>
> #11 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189):
> include('/data/web/A1423...')
>
> #12 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
>
> #13 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>
> #14 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>
> #15 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(516):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>
> #16 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(467):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('order_items',
> true)
>
> #17 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/view.phtml(64):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('order_items')
>
> #18 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189):
> include('/data/web/A1423...')
>
> #19 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
>
> #20 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>
> #21 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>
> #22 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(516):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>
> #23 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(463):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('sales.order.vie...',
> true)
>
> #24 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Wrapper.php(52):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('', true, true)
>
> #25 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674):
> Mage_Page_Block_Html_Wrapper->_toHtml()
>
> #26 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>
> #27 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674):
> Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
>
> #28 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(516):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>
> #29 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(467):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content',
> true)
>
> #30 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(48):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
>
> #31 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(189):
> include('/data/web/A1423...')
>
> #32 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(225):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
>
> #33 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(242):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
>
> #34 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(674):
> Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
>
> #35 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(536):
> Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
>
> #36 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(389):
> Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
>
> #37 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController.php(100):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
>
> #38 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/OrderController.php(136):
> Mage_Sales_OrderController->_viewAction()
>
> #39 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418):
> Mage_Sales_OrderController->viewAction()
>
> #40 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
>
> #41 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(177):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
>
> #42 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304):
> Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
>
> #43 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(596):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
>
> #44 /data/web/A14237/htdocs/magento/index.php(78):
> Mage::run('', 'store')
>
> #45 {main}

gtx,
koko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google -> I'm feeling lucky -> http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3791/

; )

Comment: Hmm, why do you think it's a problem about the charset? Everything else in the shop is working. This error occours only in this specific menu "view orders"...

Comment: I've only ever seen that iconv error in relation to charset. Are you using non-latin characters in your orders?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the german language pack (Locale_Mage_community_de_DE 1.4.0.5 (stable)). This error only occurs when the order contains non-latin chars. I changed my index.php and the .htaccess like in this thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/3791/, but it made no difference.